# iPhone: Fastest way to create a binary Plist with simple key/value strings

Tags: iphone, cocoa, objective-c, plist

What's the best way to create a binary plist on the iPhone with simple string based key/value pairs? I need to create a plist with a list of recipe and ingredients. I then want to be able to read this into an NSDictionary so I can do something like

```
NSString *ingredients = [recipes objectForKey:@"apple pie"];
```

I'm reading in an XML data file through an HTTP request and want to parse all of the key value pairs into the plist. The XML might look something like:

```
<recipes>
   <recipe> 
     <name>apple pie</name>
     <ingredients>apples and pie</ingredients>
   </recipe>
   <recipe>
     <name>cereal</name>
     <ingredients>milk and some other ingredients</ingredients>
   </recipe>
</recipes>
```

Ideally, I'll be able to write this to a plist at runtime, and then be able to read it and turn it into an NSDictionary later at runtime as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Property List in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH5-SW1)

This contains information for creating a property list file using either CoreFoundation or Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, look at the interface for NSDictionary and use:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path;
```

If you only need one fairly small dictionary, you could also try NSUserDefaults.

```
- (void)setObject:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;
```